# C чего начать изучение UNIX/LINUX?

Tags: книги, unix, linux, debian

Нужно изучить `UNIX`.

Я программирую на `Java` и все наши продукты развернуты на `UNIX`-стендах. Нужно знать как оно устроено, команды итд. С точки зрения пользовательских программ - знать не нужно.

1. Насколько реально изучать `UNIX` на винде, на которой стоит виртуальная машина? будут ли какие-то ограничения?
2. Какую именно версию `UNIX` лучше поставить для целей изучения? у нас часто используется `Debian`, это ок? Там есть какие-нибудь разные `editions` как у винды?
3. Какую книжку-две посоветуете для моих целей для изучения с нуля? англ - ок.

Comment: Ставьте на VirtualBox ubuntu или xubuntu (обе debian) и изучайте. Материала в гугле  море.

Лично у меня Ubuntu с интерфейсом xfce из xubuntu (мне оконный интерфейс Unity из ubuntu не нравится, но после установки легко доставить xfce).

--

По поводу книжек. Я считаю, что надо прочесть shell и соответственно основные команды пользователя (без этого никуда) и что-нибудь по программированию на Си с системными вызовами.

Потом почитайте man-ы (начинайте с `man man`, а потом man N-раздела intro).

Comment: можете начать с легендарной книги run linux, которая с ковбоем

Comment: почему ubuntu, а не debian? мне нужно знать как работать с серверами, они все на debian как я понимаю

Comment: ubuntu также активно используется и на серверах.

В принципе большой разницы между ними нет, но многие считают ubuntu более дружественной для пользователя

Comment: @KutaBeach, по моему опыту большинство серьезных серверов на Linux это RedHat (ближайший свободный клон - CentOS) оба на дистрибутиве fedora.

Вот между  fedor-ой и debian-ом есть некоторые отличия. Хотя... все \*nix-ы похожи (если не смотреть на что-то типа Unicos (это старый Cray) и Tandem NonStop) как и швейные машинки :)

Comment: @avp меня если честно Centos и Fedora в entrprise всегда удивляли. RHEL я ещё понимаю зачем ставить (саппорт), а вот зачем устраивать себе проблемы с centos никогда не понимал, для меня главный минус - всякий простейший софт откуда-то с левых мест всё время тянуть, тем самым понижая безопасность. А вообще да, для того чтобы быть админом  надо знать хотя-бы дебиан и редхатоподобные дистры.

Comment: У RHEL секурность выше, по типу *BSD: все что не разрешено - запрещено.

Хотя однажды после того как часов 10 промудился с настройкой такого сервака осознал что отключил почти все чтоб заработало (открыл порты, вырубил WatchDog'а, еще чего-то там...)

Comment: debian это не unix. Советую сначала почитать литературы, тем более что пользовательский уровень не нужен.

Comment: @spirit, а чем, по Вашему мнению, принципиально Linux (debian это один из его дистрибутивов) от Unix отличается?

Comment: Тем, что это разные операционные системы. Со своими системами инициализации, управления ПО и ядром. Этого мало?

Comment: Конечно мало. 

--

Дело тут даже не в том, что все это POSIX системы. 

А дело в том, что в своей основе, есле хотите, в идеологии  своего устройства (минимально open, close, read, write, fork, exec, exit (принципиально-то больше и не надо) и концепции *все есть файл*) они одинаковы.

В деталях, естественно, различия есть. Между многими \*nix-ами есть существенные архитектурные отличия, но от этого прикладное (не уровень ядра и близкие темы) программирование в них (что и спрашивает ТС) принципиально не меняется.

Comment: По одной лишь концепции "всё есть файл" равнять все ОС под одну гребенку, ну как-то неправильно вообще-то. А из-за того, что такие как Вы, не считают правильным поправлять таких как ТС, и выросло поколение школьников, для которых и бубунта операционной системой является. 
Пустой разговор, в котором, сказать, Вы сами понимаете, что не правы, но тем не менее..

Comment: > поколение школьников, для которых и бубунта операционной системой является

одноклассники раздражают?

вы пишете с кучей пунктуационных ошибок, и считаете это нормально. И это в принципе нормально, потому что мы вас понимаем. Вот так и для ТС и для всех понтно что unix/linux это разные ОСи, но их можно обобщить, потому уж очень у них общего.

Comment: Да нет, люблю одноклассников, виделись только очень уж давно. А насчет пунктуационных ошибок, то неплохо было бы, если уж делаете замечание, то в замечании хотя бы их самому не допускать) ага)
Насчет приобщения я уже Вам сказал, Вы очень далеки от истины и не особо "рубите" в этом направлении, судя по Вашим постам.

Comment: Ну дык я и есть та самая школота, мне позволительно.

Comment: @spirit

      Со своими системами инициализации, управления ПО и ядром. Этого мало?

А какие ядра у UNIX (1). Можно или нет отнести к UNIX'ам системы *bsd (и почему). 

Ну люблю я заявления "linux != unix" :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Есть один проверенный лично метод:

Ставьте разные дистрибутивы на реальную тачку: Debian, Fedora, Slackware. В общем главное чтоб дистры были "разные".

После установки настраивайте систему под себя: драйвера, GUI, приложения.

В таком раскладе как раз столкнетесь и с терминалом, и с особенностями той или иной ОС.

Выбрав таким образом понравившийся дистр, попробуйте пользоваться им некоторое время, так и научитесь, со временем.

В общем вам поможет **практика**.

**UPD**

Советую не ставить на виртуалку, т.к. в случае возникновения какой-то проблемы будет соблазн дропнуть вирт-машину и вернуться в зону комфорта, вместо того чтобы все исправить.

Comment: Могу сказать о себе, что более глубокое понимание линукса я получил после того как установил и настроил Linux Arch с нуля и еще сильнее оно увеличилось после того, как пришлось настроить сервак(для маленького предприятия) в голой консоли. В общем да - практика помогает лучше всего, а книги это лишь помошники в этом пути.

Comment: я по этой системе методом тыка линукс изучал, пока не нашел tab и man (интернета тогда почти не было, было fido)

Comment: да, после Linux Arch настройки в консоли - хоть куда! )

Comment: @eicto про команду apropos тоже полезно знать, хотя в инете сейчас найти ответ проще.

А фидошная ru.linux (под модерацией Б. Тоботраса) была довольно неплохой эхой.

Comment: Правильно говорят, чтобы совсем углубиться в изучение и понимание, нужно уметь ставить систему из консоли... Arch, Gentoo к примеру...

Answer (score 4):

Как стать системным администратором или стать на шаг ближе к ним? Этим вопросом задаются многие и единого ответа не существует.. 
на уровень пользователя - продвинутого пользователя инструкцию Вам описал предыущий оратор

- гуглите интсрукцию как установить тот или иной дистрибутив
- качаете чисто консольный пакет без всяких гуевин
- инсталлите с наименьшим количеством предустановленного по
- далее решаете поставленные задачи, например:
- графическую оболку ( несколько разных с попеременным удалением предидущей)
- далее настраиваем сеть
- далее дрова в т.ч и вафельные если такое имеется и чем специфичнее у вас конфигурация тем лучше (некоторые radeonовкие карты = 7 кругов ада)
- после того как у Вас из линуксовой операционки получится столь же удобный и привычный декстоп как на винде ( или отдаленно напоминающий оный ) начинайте настраивать уже сервера и прочие необходимые окружения

все это в обнимку с гуглом

- после этого, в получившейся НеФорточной системе поднимаете виртуалку (она вам пригодится не только для экспериментов), опять же пробуйте разные пока не придет четкое понимание как и с какой работать ( qemu+kvm, VirtualBox, прочие)

ну и наверно тут и будет некоторый профит по вашему вопросу, так же рекомендую почитать на досуге книжечку "TCP/IP крупным планом" - это не библия, но знать необходимо

Answer (score 0):

Несколько тезисов из своего опыта для целей ТС:

- выбирайте дистрибутив "общего
     назначения", "универсальный
     первородный конструктор" - типа
     Fedora, Debian, Slackware... Не
     выбирайте производные, а тем более т.
     н. "кастомные" дистрибутивы
- используйте этот дистрибутив на
     реальной машине, желательно в
     качестве единственной системы
- перед переходом запаситесь Live-CD с
     Knoppix, например, для возможности
     быстрой починки
- предпочитайте консоль гую
- редактируйте текстовые файлы
     нативными консольными средствами
- читайте встроенную документацию - это
     информация "из первых рук"
- не поддавайтесь унынию, если что-то
     не будет получаться ;-)